# Excluding all elements but one

Tags: php

I have an array of things: `$arr = array('Apple', 'Pear', 'Pineapple');`

I want to exclude everything apart from, say, 'Apple' in the array. I had a look at using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), however I don't know how I would apply using that in my situation.

Doing `array_diff($arr, array('Apple'));` obviously excludes 'Apple' from the list.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** Since more details are required, I have to process data from an API I'm using which takes an exclusion list to simplify the JSON response. Therefore I'm using the array containing possible options to exclude.

Comment: What? You want one element back, and you know the value of the element you're looking for? `in_array`...

Comment: I need it for an exclusion list in a rest api I'm using

Comment: More detail needed.  What you have works, so what do you need that is different?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma Nobody asked what you want it for.

Comment: `array_intersect($arr, array('Apple'));`??? Gives "Apple".

Comment: Maybe an "I have this", "given this", "I want to get this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more elegant solution:

```
$arr = array('Apple', 'Pear', 'Pineapple');

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($element) {
        return $element != "Apple";
});

print_r($newArr);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Pear
    [2] => Pineapple
)
```

Or, if you need to exclude everything but `Apple`, just change the `return` statement to `return $element == "Apple";`

**Update**

You say it's not an elegant solution, because

> variable scope would not find a parameter of a function to be used there. i.e. method parameter `$param1` could not be used for return `$element == $param1;`

But it can. You just don't know about `use`:

```
$arr = array('Apple', 'Pear', 'Pineapple');
$param = "Apple";

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($element) use ($param) {
        return $element != $param;
});
```

Now, `$newArr` still contains the requested

```
Array
(
    [1] => Pear
    [2] => Pineapple
)
```

Comment: This would be more elegant, but variable scope would not find a parameter of a function to be used there. i.e. method parameter `$param1` could not be used for `return $element == $param1;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are iterating through the array and not just simply removing 'Apple' values from the array... you can add a condition check inside a loop which checks for any value.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($value != 'Apple'){ //array value is not 'Apple,' do something
        //do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can duplicate the array and exclude whatever you want with a simple function:

```
<?php

function copy_arr_exclude_byVal(array &$arrIn, ...$values){
    $arrOut = array();
    if(isset($values) && count($values) > 0){
        foreach($arrIn as $arrKey => $arrValue){
            if(!in_array($arrValue, $values)){
                $arrOut[] = $arrValue;
                //to keep original key names: $arrOut[$arrKey] = $arrValue;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $arrOut = $arrIn;
        return($arrOut);//no exclusions, copy and return array
    }
    return($arrOut);
}


/* TEST */
$testArr = array('test1', 'test2', 'foo', 'bar');
$newArr = copy_arr_exclude_byVal($testArr, 'foo');

echo var_dump($newArr);
```

Also, you can look into the native function array_filter(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Modified to push exclusions to an array for my own use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Function `array_intersect()` also may be helpful in your case. For example:

```php
array_intersect(array('Apple', 'Pear', 'Pineapple'), array('Apple', 'Watermelon'));
```

will give an array with intersected values: `['Apple']`